# changing the dropdown text based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have the following code, working fine:

```
<div class="btn-group"> 
    <a class="btn mini all" id="showall" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="dropdown">All<i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="none">None</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read">Read</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="unread">Unread</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now i am trying to do is if i select none, it should place none at top and all at none's place, same with the other two read and unread

so here is my try with jquery, i am missing or overlapping something so it is replacing all and none with all while toggling

```
$(document).on('click','.none',function(e) {
        $("#showall").html('').html("None <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>");
        $(".none").html('').html('All').removeClass('none').addClass('new');
    });
    $(document).on('click',".read", function(e) {
        var data = $("#showall").text();
        $("#showall").html('').html("Read <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>");
        $(".read").html('').html(data).removeClass('read').addClass('new');;
    });
    $(document).on('click',".unread", function(e) {
        var data = $("#showall").text();
        $("#showall").html('').html("Unread <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>");
        $(".unread").html('').html(data).removeClass('unread').addClass('new');
    });
    $(document).on('click',".new", function(e) {
        var data = $("#showall").text();
        $("#showall").html('').html("All <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>");
        $(".new").html('').html(data).removeClass('new read unread').addClass('none');
    });
```

Comment: Just for your information: Don't use javascript:void(0); it kills SEO, use `event.preventDefault();` instead or `return false;`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should give a common class to all of your `<a>` items, for example 'clickable'.

Then you can write something like this:

```
// bind 'onclick' event to all your links
$('.clickable').click(function(event){
    // replaces your javascript:void(0) as Frondor suggests
    event.preventDefault();
    // if clicked element is not a direct child of '.btn-group' (currently 'selectall')
    if($(this).parent('.btn-group').lenght === 0){
        // move the direct child of '.btn-group' (currently 'selectall') after the clicked element
        $(this).after($('.btn-group>a'));
        // move the clicked element to the beginning of the '.btn-group'
        $('.btn-group').prepend($(this));
    }
});
```

I'm not sure what's with all these classes and ids you're using, and especially this `<i>` tag. But if you really need to add them every time, you can do it inside this event callback.

Comment: `$('.btn-group').prepand($(this));` should be `.prepend()` but anyway, I don't think that code works.

Comment: @Frondor Thanks, fixed the typo. But what would not work in this code?

Comment: Isn't `$('.btn-group').prepend($(this));`actually "pre-pending" the whole `.btn-group` element and childs?

Comment: No, it's moving $(this), which is the clicked element, to be the first element inside '.btn-group'. prependTo() would do what you think.

Comment: cool! Tanks But the class .dropdown-menu is also used with other pieces, so it is overwriting all can i do something else here

Comment: What do you mean? What is overwriting what?

Comment: `<div class="btn-group"><a class="btn mini all" id="showall" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="dropdown">All<i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="none">None</a></li><li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read">Read</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="unread">Unread</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>` i have `btn-group` and `dropdown-menu` defined with other same types having different things, like the classes are used same. overall the functoin is doing pretty well much i want...

Comment: Then use ids. You can have multiple items with class `btn-group`, but only one with the id, for example `btn-group_1`. So you have `<div class="btn-group" id="btn-group_1">...`, and then select with `'#btn-group_1'` using jQuery. Like in `$(this).parent('#btn-group_1').lenght`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is to *swap* the main (top) link with the clicked link within the `dropdown-menu`, you can do it like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var ddClass = $(this).attr('class');
        var ddHref = $(this).attr('href');
        var ddText = $(this).text();        

        var $a = $('.btn-group a.btn');
        var aClass = $a.attr('class');
        var aId = $a.attr('id');
        var aHref = $a.attr('href');
        var aText = $a.text();

        $a.replaceWith(function () {
            var $newA = $('<a>', { 
                href: ddHref, 
                id: ddClass,
                class: aClass,
                'data-toggle': 'dropdown'                
            }).text(ddText);

            var $newI = $('<i>', { class: 'fa fa-angle-down' });         
            $newA.append($newI);

            return $newA;
        });

        $(this).replaceWith(function () {
            return $('<a>', { 
                href: aHref, 
                class: aId                
            }).text(aText);
        });
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w5g1v4f7/1/)

**Note:** As mentioned in the comments, avoid the use of `href="javascript:void(0);"` because it messes up with the SEO.